# How to change the html table row color on PHP fetched row value?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to change the color of my table row on the bases of any cell value.
As, I am using JQuery, PHP & MYSQL.
On Page load I am including PHP file that contains one function that fetch the all rows from the MYSQl table and return it back to the UI page.
The way I am fetching is as
temp1.php contains below partial code

```
                                <?php  echo fxn_ExpensesList(); 

                                ?>
                             </tbody>
                           <tfoot>
```

and the main php file contains the below code as:

```
$Lquery = "SELECT * FROM tblexpenseslist";
$Lquery_result = mysqli_query($conn, $Lquery);

$dataRow = "";
$RowsCounter = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Lquery_result)){
        ++$RowsCounter;
        $dataRow = $dataRow."<tr><td>$RowsCounter</td>
            <td>$row[ExpensesType]</td>
            <td>$row[Purpose]</td>
            <td>$row[Description]</td>
            <td>$row[ReceiptNo]</td>
            <td>$row[PAID]</td>
            <td>$row[DTime]</td>
            <td>$row[UnitPrice]</td>
            <td>$row[Qty]</td>
            <td>$row[Amount]</td>
            <td style='display:none;'>$row[SNo]</td>
            <td>
                <p data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Edit'>
                    <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-edit' data-title='Edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit' >
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>
                    </button>
                </p>
            </td>
            <!--<td><p data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete'><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' data-title='Delete' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#delete' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></button></p></td>-->

            </tr>"; 
    }

return $dataRow;
```

Now, I want to add one more functionality to the table row if the amount is paid or not.. I am thinking for that but nothing strikes to mind.

Comment: Add if else condition and change  `$dataRow` inside them

Comment: Point is that, where to add if else condition

Comment: What does this method do `fxn_ExpensesList()` and how is it being used?

Comment: @JSalaria I left the question because I don't know if you're here or not. If you want my attention, you will need to @ me as I did here; good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class to a table row and then modify that class using jQuery.

For example, you can make a variable called `paid` as a boolean value.  If the specific row is paid for, then add the class `isPaid` to the table row.  If not, then add the class `notPaid`, like this...

```
if (paid == true) {
  '<tr class="isPaid">'
else if (paid != true) {
  '<tr class="notPaid">'
}
```

...then using jQuery you can do something like...

```
$('.isPaid').css('background-color', 'green');
$('.notPaid').css('background-color', 'red')
```

Or something of the sort.

Comment: Use CSS to add styles

Comment: I want to try something in this way. 
echo "<td>".$row['PAID']. if($row['PAID'] == 'NPaid'){
       "<tr style='background-color:red;'>";
     }"</td>"; 
But no success